# Call SOAP request operation in Node.js

Tags: node.js, soap, node-soap

I'm trying to make a SOAP request using node-soap - I can successful create a client but when I try to call the operation defined in the WSDL it returns `undefined`? Is this how I correctly call an operation?

```
const soap = require('soap');
const btoa = require('btoa');

response = {}
exports.getInventory = async (event, context) => {

    let username = '******';
    let password = '**********';

    let wsdlUrl = 'https://webservices.onewaybike.nl/CubeServices.svc?wsdl';

    const security = new soap.BasicAuthSecurity(username, password);

    let client = await soap.createClientAsync(wsdlUrl);
    client.setSecurity(security)
    
    let args = { Year: 2020}

    let dataResponse = await client.GetStockInfoNewOrdersForSeason(args)
    console.log(dataResponse)

    response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: "Inventory retrieved."
    };

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `Async` Method.
Append `Async` to the method GetStockInfoNewOrdersForSeason**Async**

```js
let [dataResponse] = await client.GetStockInfoNewOrdersForSeasonAsync(args)
```

The response is an Array.
From the [npm soap documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#client) :

> Client.methodAsync(args, options) - call method on the SOAP service.
>
> ```js
>  client.MyFunctionAsync({name: 'value'}).then((result) => {
>    // result is a javascript array containing result, rawResponse, soapheader, and rawRequest
>    // result is a javascript object
>    // rawResponse is the raw xml response string
>    // soapHeader is the response soap header as a javascript object
>    // rawRequest is the raw xml request string
>  })
> ```